# How would encryption at rest have protected Equifax?

Tags: encryption

I keep seeing statements like this:

> Without full knowledge about who is ‘at fault’ – the main point is that the information needs to be encrypted at rest, and any single application/service/user access is decrypted as part of the transaction...

This is from a [HashedOut blog post](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/equifax-data-breach-learn/?utm_source=HashedOutRSS&utm_medium=EmailLink&utm_campaign=HashedOutEmail&utm_source=HashedOut&utm_campaign=0d6efeb4fc-HashedOut_RSS_EMAIL&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_21c4367032-0d6efeb4fc-91319941&ct=t(RSS_EMAIL_CAMPAIGN)&goal=0_21c4367032-0d6efeb4fc-91319941&mc_cid=0d6efeb4fc&mc_eid=0e19dd4aef) about what was learned from the Equifax breach in 2017.

How would encryption of that data have prevented the exposure of the data? For the data to be usable the encryption has to be transparent to the user and the application. Since the running system was compromised wouldn't that give the attacker the same transparent access to the data thus rendering the encryption useless in that scenario? If not, how does at rest encryption protect from an on-line attack?